# Write R Data frame into Snowflake

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert a R data frame into Snowflake but I am getting error as "table already exists" though I have added append = TRUE

```
table_id <- Id(database="database", schema="schema", table="tablename")
dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name,append=TRUE,overwrite=FALSE)
```

Is there anything I am missing ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you attempting to write to a non-default schema? See [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/91)

Comment: @sergiu No I dont have that issue

Comment: What R package  and connector versions are you using ?  

Can you provide sessionInfo() output ?

Are you using ODBC or JDBC ?